# Dont know how to repaint() in Java

Tags: java

I want to draw an `ImageIcon`.

```
public class Test extends JPanel {

    static ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("AAA.png");
    static JFrame j;

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        image.paintIcon(j, g, 200, 200);       
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        j = new JFrame();
        j.setSize(700, 700);
        j.repaint();
        j.setVisible(true); 
    }
}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: You need to create an instance of Test and add it to the frame

Comment: OK, thank you very much !  can you explain me why need to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i just want to draw imageicon...

Then add the Icon to a JLabel and add the label to the frame. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Icons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) for more information and working examples.

Get rid of all those static variables. That is an indication of a poor class design.

Also, there is no need for the repaint() statement. The frame isn't even visible yet so that statement does nothing.

Download the example from the tutorial and use it as a template for a better way to code your class. Learn the basics from the demo code.

Comment: public class Test extends JPanel{

    static ImageIcon image= new ImageIcon("AAA.png");

    static JFrame j;
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        image.paintIcon(j, g, 200, 200);       
    }

    public Test {
        j=new JFrame();
        j.setSize(700,700);
        j.repaint();
        j.setVisible(true); 
    }
}

Comment: @mat, Please delete the above comment. I have no idea what that code is for. It has no relevance to my suggestion. Code related to the question should be posted in the question.